# How to monitor MSMQ perfomance counters for different roles in windows cluster

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-cluster, msmq, performance-counters

By default it is not possible to view perf counters for clusterd instance of MSMQ in windows cluster. The solution is to create a registry key NetNameForPerfCounters and assign role name to it. This way it is possible to monitor only one role per cluster. How can I monitor several roles with clustered MSMQ in each one?